# Finding the order of a permutation $\sigma$ and thus using it to find $\sigma^{122}$

Tags: permutations, permutation-cycles

I have a given $\sigma$ which is:

$$\left({1\atop5}{2\atop8}{3\atop3}{4\atop4}{5\atop6}{6\atop1}{7\atop7}{8\atop2}\right)\in S_8$$

I need to find the order of this permutation, as it is necessary to solve $\sigma^{122}$

My feeling is that once you have the order, the solution is to find the remainder of the power  following the division by the order of the permutation.

e.g

If the order is $5, \frac{122}{5} = 24.5$

$24\cdot 5 = 120$ meaning that  $σ^{122} = σ^{120} \cdot σ^2 = σ^2$

Comment: Write $\sigma$ as a product of disjoint cycles: $(156)(28)$. Then it is obvious that its order is 6.

Comment: Once you write $\sigma$ as a product of disjoint cycles, you can use [the fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290281/calculate-the-order-in-cycle-notation) that a product of disjoint cycles has order equal to the least common multiple of the lengths of the cycles.

Comment: Your argument once you know the order is right. But $122/5 = 24 + 2/5$, not $24.5$. You should not use decimals (even correct ones) when doing rational number arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, as mentioned in a comment, the decomposition as a product of disjoint cycles is
$$\sigma=(1\,5\,6)(2\,8).$$
As these cycles commute, the order of $\sigma$ is the l.c.m. of the orders of the cycles, which is respectively $3$ and $2$. Now, 
$$\sigma^{122}=(1\,5\,6)^{122} (2\,8)^{122}=(1\,5\,6)^{122\bmod 3} (2\,8)^{122\bmod 2}=(1\,5\,6)^{-1}=(1\,6\,5).$$

Comment: @MatthewDaly: Oh! yes. Sorry for the copy-paste error. Thank you for pointing it!

Comment: Would it not result in (1 5 6) ^2 since 122mod3 is 2? or am I missing a step.

Comment: Yes but it's the same since $2\equiv -1\bmod 3$, and it's shorter to determine the inverse of a cycle than its square.