# Given a permutation $\sigma = (13)(254)$, state $\sigma^2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutation-cycles

Given a permutation $\sigma = (13)(254)$, state $\sigma^2$.

$\sigma = (13)(254), \sigma^2=(13)(254)(13)(254) = (13)(13)(254)(254) = (425)
$

Or, in two row format, get:
$$ \sigma = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 \\ 3 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 5 &4 \\ 5 & 4 & 2\end{pmatrix} $$

Then, $$\sigma^2=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 \\ 3 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 5 &4 \\ 5 & 4 & 2\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 \\ 3 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 5 &4 \\ 5 & 4 & 2\end{pmatrix}
$$

Due to disjoint cycles, they can commute as no affect on map produced.

$$\sigma^2=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 \\ 3 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 \\ 3 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 5 &4 \\ 5 & 4 & 2\end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 5 &4 \\ 5 & 4 & 2\end{pmatrix}
$$

My answer is:

$$\sigma^2=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 \\ 1 & 3 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 5 &4 \\ 4 & 2 & 5\end{pmatrix}
= e.\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 5 &4 \\ 4 & 2 & 5\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 5 &4 \\ 4 & 2 & 5\end{pmatrix}
$$

But, the answer is different: $(245)$?

Comment: Your first computation of $(2~5~4)^2$ is wrong.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan then second too is, as just two row format. But, how?

Comment: $(2\ \ 5\ \ 4)^2 = (2\ \ 4\ \ 5)$.

Comment: How is your answer different from $(2~4~5)$? In your answer $2 \mapsto 4$, $4\mapsto 5$ and $5 \mapsto 2$ which is exactly $(2~4~5)$.

Comment: @RandyMarsh thanks, in one row form it is correctly seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

$$\begin{align}
\sigma^2&=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5\\3&5&1&2&4\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5\\3&5&1&2&4\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5\\1&4&3&5&2\end{pmatrix}\\
&=(245).
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$\begin{align}
\sigma^2&=(13)(254)(13)(254)\\
&=(13)(13)(254)(254)\\
&=(254)^2\\
&=(245)
\end{align}$$

because

$$\begin{align}
1&\xrightarrow{(254)}1\xrightarrow{(254)}1,\\
2&\xrightarrow{(254)}5\xrightarrow{(254)}4,\\
3&\xrightarrow{(254)}3\xrightarrow{(254)}3,\\
4&\xrightarrow{(254)}2\xrightarrow{(254)}5,\\
5&\xrightarrow{(254)}4\xrightarrow{(254)}2.\\
\end{align}$$

In row format,

$$\begin{align}
\sigma^2&=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
3 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 4
\end{pmatrix}^2\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
3 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 4
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
3 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 4
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
1 & 4 & 3 & 5 & 2
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align}$$

which gives $(245)$ again.

Comment: Very happy, as was unable to understand your answer at: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3787695/513178.